# How to use pointers to interface in go as internal data structure for collection-like types?

Tags: go, templates, interface

**TLDR;** I need to use pointers to interface e.g. `*Comparable` as an internal `Data`'s object in my `Node` as a part of `Tree`. `Data` should conform to pointer to `Comparable` interface that has only one method `Less` which compares two objects of `Comparable` interface type.

If I am using just `Comparable` as type for `Data` in `Node`, without pointer, everything works fine. However after I switch to `*Comparable` compiler gives strange errors and code won't compile

Code with `Comparable`:

```
package main

type Comparable interface {
    Less(than Comparable) bool
}

type Node struct {
    Data Comparable
}

func NewNode(data Comparable) *Node {
    return &Node{Data: data} }

type Tree struct {
    root *Node
}

func NewTree() *Tree {
    return &Tree{}
}

func (t *Tree) insert(data Comparable) {
    if t.root == nil || t.root.Data.Less(data) {
        t.root = NewNode(data)
    }
}

type Row struct {
    Row []string
}

func NewRow(row[] string) *Row {
    return &Row{Row: row}
}

func (r Row) Less(other Comparable) bool {
    return r.Row[0] < other.(Row).Row[0]
}

func main() {
    t := NewTree()
    t.insert(*NewRow([]string{"123"}))
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", t.root.Data.(Row).Row)
}
```

tests:

```
package main

import (
    "reflect"
    "testing"
)

func TestInsert(t *testing.T) {
    d := []string{"42"}
    tree := NewTree()
    tree.insert(*NewRow(d))
    if !reflect.DeepEqual(tree.root.Data.(Row).Row, d) {
        t.Error("returned elements are not matching")
    }
}

func TestInsert2x(t *testing.T) {
    d1 := []string{"42"}
    d2 := []string{"99"}
    tree := NewTree()
    tree.insert(*NewRow(d1))
    tree.insert(*NewRow(d2))
    if !reflect.DeepEqual(tree.root.Data.(Row).Row, d2) {
        t.Error("returned elements are not matching")
    }
}
```

However when I convert `Comparable` to `*Comparable`, everything breaks and the root cause is something like `*Row` is not equal to `*Comparable` compiler error:

for line `return r.Row[0] < other.(*Row).Row[0]`

> Invalid type assertion: other.(*Row) (non-interface type *Comparable on left)

and for line `if t.root == nil || t.root.Data.Less(data) {`

> Unresolved reference 'Less'

```
package main

type Comparable interface {
    Less(than *Comparable) bool
}

type Node struct {
    Data *Comparable
}

func NewNode(data *Comparable) *Node {
    return &Node{Data: data}
}

type Tree struct {
    root *Node
}

func NewTree() *Tree {
    return &Tree{}
}

func (t *Tree) insert(data *Comparable) {
    if t.root == nil || t.root.Data.Less(data) {
        t.root = NewNode(data)
    }
}

type Row struct {
    Row []string
}

func NewRow(row[] string) *Row {
    return &Row{Row: row}
}

func (r *Row) Less(other *Comparable) bool {
    return r.Row[0] < other.(*Row).Row[0]
}

func main() {
    t := NewTree()
    t.insert(NewRow([]string{"123"}))
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", t.root.Data.(*Row).Row)
}
```

tests:

```
package main

import (
    "reflect"
    "testing"
)

func TestInsert(t *testing.T) {
    d := []string{"42"}
    tree := NewTree()
    tree.insert(NewRow(d))
    if !reflect.DeepEqual(tree.root.Data.(*Row).Row, d) {
        t.Error("returned elements are not matching")
    }
}

func TestInsert2x(t *testing.T) {
    d1 := []string{"42"}
    d2 := []string{"99"}
    tree := NewTree()
    tree.insert(NewRow(d1))
    tree.insert(NewRow(d2))
    if !reflect.DeepEqual(tree.root.Data.(*Row).Row, d2) {
        t.Error("returned elements are not matching")
    }
}
```

The question is how to use `*Comparable` as type of `Data` in `Node` so that code above compiles. I tried a couple ugly options with `interface{}` type for `Data` and explicit casts everywhere. This approach I didn't like as it is very unsafe.

You can check all code parts in [my github repo](https://github.com/igavrysh/go-pointer-to-interface)

Comment: Why would you want to use a pointer to an interface? They are almost never a good idea in Go. Interfaces can already hold pointers to structs, as you've discovered. You say that using a regular `Comparable` interface "works fine", so why do you want to change it?

Comment: If I just use `Comparable` in `Node` that will mean that all `Data` is copied with `Node`, when I pass it to function or when I copy, construct or recreate a tree. I want to escape this coping in my code.

Comment: Use case: you already have huge `type Row struct { Row string }` objects (instead of `slice of strings` as in code above, just a `string`) created somewhere. And you want to avoid copying `Row` strings at all cost.

Answer (score 2):

Interfaces can accept both structs and pointers to structs.

You can pass in a pointer to Row (`*Row`) to `Tree.insert(data Comparable)`, by combining your 1st `Tree.insert(data Comparable)` function definition with your 2nd `main()` function calls.

Here's a full running example, also on Go Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/Gh_RT3R-Fy0 .

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Comparable interface {
    Less(than Comparable) bool
}

type Node struct {
    Data Comparable
}

func NewNode(data Comparable) *Node {
    return &Node{Data: data}
}

type Tree struct {
    root *Node
}

func NewTree() *Tree {
    return &Tree{}
}

func (t *Tree) insert(data Comparable) {
    if t.root == nil || t.root.Data.Less(data) {
        t.root = NewNode(data)
    }
}

type Row struct {
    Row []string
}

func NewRow(row []string) *Row {
    return &Row{Row: row}
}

func (r Row) Less(other Comparable) bool {
    return r.Row[0] < other.(*Row).Row[0]
}

func main() {
    t := NewTree()
    t.insert(NewRow([]string{"123"}))
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", t.root.Data.(*Row).Row)
}
```

That being said, this is brittle code since the `Row.Less` function accesses the underlying type of `Comparable` and assumes the array has at a 0 index value (length > 0).

```golang
func (r Row) Less(other Comparable) bool {
    return r.Row[0] < other.(*Row).Row[0]
}
```

It's much better to remove any dependency on the underlying type of `Comparable` when interface functions are called. You can do this augmenting the `Comparable` interface and `Row.Less` definition as follows. In this approach, there's no need to cast in the `Row` struct definition.

On Go Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/8-71-pEn-zK

```golang
type Comparable interface {
    Less(than Comparable) bool
    CompareValue() string
}

func (r Row) CompareValue() string {
    if len(r.Row) == 0 {
        return ""
    }
    return r.Row[0]
}

func (r Row) Less(other Comparable) bool {
    return r.CompareValue() < other.CompareValue()
}
```

For more information on pointer to interfaces, see the Go FAQ on using pointers to interfaces:

https://golang.org/doc/faq#pointer_to_interface

> **When should I use a pointer to an interface?**
>
> Almost never. Pointers to interface values arise only in rare, tricky situations involving disguising an interface value's type for delayed evaluation.
>
> It is a common mistake to pass a pointer to an interface value to a function expecting an interface. The compiler will complain about this error but the situation can still be confusing, because sometimes a [pointer is necessary to satisfy an interface](https://golang.org/doc/faq#different_method_sets). The insight is that although a pointer to a concrete type can satisfy an interface, with one exception a pointer to an interface can never satisfy an interface.
>
> [...]
>
> The one exception is that any value, even a pointer to an interface, can be assigned to a variable of empty interface type (`interface{}`). Even so, it's almost certainly a mistake if the value is a pointer to an interface; the result can be confusing.

Comment: Thx for reply! Code above needs a fix in Less func: `func (r *Row) Less(other Comparable) bool { return r.Row[0] < other.(*Row).Row[0] }`. E.g. https://play.golang.org/p/VfJrt53HO8L. Are there any ways to catch those kind of errors? This cast to *Row: `.(*Row)` looks very unsafe. Are there any ways to escape it altogether?

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the `Less` function, but as you've noticed, this code is brittle. The issue isn't the pointer but that you're casting to something the interface doesn't define. The cast to Row, `.(Row)` in the `Row.Less` function is just as unsafe as well since you are assuming the `other Comparable` value is a `Row`, in which case you don't need to use an interface at all. To make this safer with the `Comparable` interface, you can augment the interface with another function like `Comparable.CompareValue()` which returns a vaue to compare which I've added to the answer.